# Need a control/solution that will be used as a container for storing values from the textfield in yii

Tags: php, forms, yii

Here's what I want to do: (in yii)

I have multiple textFields (around 6), in a form. I need a control that will used as a container for storing values from the textFields (meaning one container for each textField as more values will be added to the container from the same textField on button click), and that control should be accessible from yii model or controller.

Is there any control or any way to achieve this?

Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**In view**

**For Active records**

```
<?php echo $form->textField($model,'title[]',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>1000)); ?>
```

**CHtml**

```
<?php echo CHtml::textField('title[]','Title'); ?>
```

You can use multiple input's with same name by array of name

**In controller**

You can get these values as array with the name of you posted

i prefer [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/jqrelcopy/) to you